# Use of 'Empty Target' in makefile

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

Lately I've been trying to get into the concepts of GNU Make. While reading, I came accross a topic called **Empty Target**. From [GNU Make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Empty-Targets) what I got to know is

> The empty target is a variant of the phony target; it is used to hold
>   recipes for an action that you request explicitly from time to time.
>   Unlike a phony target, this target file can really exist; but the
>   file's contents do not matter, and usually are empty.
>
> The purpose of the empty target file is to record, with its
>   last-modification time, when the rule's recipe was last executed. It
>   does so because one of the commands in the recipe is a touch command
>   to update the target file.

From [another source](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=rL4GthWj9kcC&lpg=PP1&dq=managing%20projects%20with%20gnu%20make&pg=PT117#v=snippet&q=empty%20targets&f=false), I read something like this

> Empty targets are similar to phony targets in that the target itself
>   is used as a device to leverage the capabilities of make. Phony
>   targets are always out of date, so they always execute and they always
>   cause their dependent (the target associated with the prerequisite) to
>   be remade. But suppose we have some command, with no output file, that
>   needs to be performed only occasionally and we don’t want our
>   dependents updated? For this, we can make a rule whose target is an
>   empty file (sometimes referred to as a cookie):
>
> ```
> prog: size prog.o
> $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
>
> size: prog.o
> size $^
> touch size
> ```
>
> Notice that the size rule uses touch to create an empty file named
>   size after it completes. This empty file is used for its timestamp so
>   that make will execute the size rule only when prog.o has been
>   updated. Furthermore, the size prerequisite to prog will not force an
>   update of prog unless its object file is also newer.

From reading them what I  understood is

- Empty target is used to maintain the timestamp
- The content of empty target is of no interest, only the update time
  is.

For doing some hands-on, I have written two sample makefiles

#### makefile 1

with empty target use

```
prog: size prog.o
    gcc -o $@ prog.o

size: prog.o
    size $<
    touch size

prog.o: prog.c
    gcc -c $<
```

*output*

```
[sourav@localhost Practice]# make
gcc -c prog.c
size prog.o
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     58       0       0      58      3a prog.o
touch size
gcc -o prog prog.o
[sourav@localhost Practice]# make
make: `prog' is up to date.
[sourav@localhost Practice]# touch prog.c //suppose some real change in the file
[sourav@localhost Practice]# make
gcc -c prog.c
size prog.o
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     58       0       0      58      3a prog.o
touch size
gcc -o prog prog.o
[sourav@localhost Practice]#
```

#### makefile 2

without empty target use

```
prog: prog.o
    size $^
    gcc -o $@ prog.o

prog.o: prog.c
    gcc -c $<
```

*output*

```
[sourav@localhost Practice]# make
gcc -c prog.c
size prog.o
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     58       0       0      58      3a prog.o
gcc -o prog prog.o
[sourav@localhost Practice]# make
make: `prog' is up to date.
[sourav@localhost Practice]# touch prog.c 
[sourav@localhost Practice]# make
gcc -c prog.c
size prog.o
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
     58       0       0      58      3a prog.o
gcc -o prog prog.o
[sourav@localhost Practice]#
```

In above two different makefiles , the output for the similar condition is same. So, I'm not clear with the particular ***scope of use*** for empty targets. If they are used only to hold the timestamp, then we can achieve the same without using them . [Or is related with automatic variable `$?` about which I'm yet to read in detail]. Can anyone resolve this confusion in some other wordings, possibly with some example (if I'm not asking too much)?

Thanks and Cheers!!

Answer (score 3):

In your case you already have a target (size), which changes when one of your source file does.
So in your example, gcc acts like touch.
However, in your first link, if you take a look at the example:

```
 print: foo.c bar.c
         lpr -p $?
         touch print
```

Here without `touch print`, `make print` will always execute `lpr -p` as the print rule does not refer to a file that changes. Example with ls:

Makefile:

```
print: foo.c bar.c
       ls $?
```

make print (1):

```
ls foo.c bar.c
bar.c foo.c
```

make print (2):

```
ls foo.c bar.c
bar.c foo.c
```

However, now if `make print` changes the timestamp of a file renamed "print", now the rule refers to an existing file:

Makefile:

```
print: foo.c bar.c
       ls $?
       touch print
```

make print (1):

```
ls foo.c bar.c
bar.c foo.c
```

make print (2):

```
make: `print' is up to date.
```

because file print is more recent than foo.c and bar.c.